# White space around JPG Format Map tiles

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to show custom map on MKMapView using tiles. But my problem is when i use png format for tiles it takes too much space in storage. but when i use jpg format tiles then white space appears around the tiles on map because jpg does not spport transparency.
Can anyone guide me how i can remove white space around my map tiles.

Red color is a overlay. 
white color is coming around the custom map .jpg tiles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use pngnq to optimise the png tiles in my overlay, and because of the content they come out smaller than jpegs.

Could you do a mix of jpegs and Pngs? The first and last from each column plus the entire side columns are they only ones you'd need to have with transparency (assuming a convex map).